# How to revoke permission on Oracle RDS granted by rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object()

Tags: oracle, amazon-rds

AWS created a procedure to grant permission on SYS objects in Oracle RDS which is "rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object()" as an alternative for using the GRANT command.

Any idea how to revoke such permission after granting it.

I tried to use the default REVOKE command but it raised error similar to the one when trying to use GRANT instead of "rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object()".

Also, i did not find any procedure in AWS Oracle RDS similar to the grant one that can revoke, e.g.: 
"rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.**revoke**_sys_object()"

Thanks.